# Downloading & extracting in parallel, maximizing performance?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, download, tar

I want to download and extract 100 tar.gz files that are each 1GB in size. Currently, I've sped it up with multithreading and by avoiding disk IO via in-memory byte streams, but can anyone show me how to make this faster (just for curiosity's sake)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import tarfile

import multiprocessing as mp
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# speed up by only extracting what we need
def select(members):
    for file in members:  
        if any(ext in file.name for ext in [".tif", ".img"]):
            yield file

# for each url download the tar.gz and extract the necessary files
def download_and_extract(x):
    # read and unzip as a byte stream
    r = requests.get(x, stream=True)
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=r.raw, mode='r|gz')
    tar.extractall(members=select(tar))
    tar.close()


# parallel download and extract the 96 1GB tar.gz files
links = get_asset_links()
# 3 * cpu count seemed to be fastest on a 4 core cpu
with ThreadPoolExecutor(3 * mp.cpu_count()) as executor:
    executor.map(download_and_extract, links)
```

My current approach takes 20 - 30 minutes. I'm not sure what the theoretical possible speed up is, but if its helpful, the download speed for a single file is 20 MB/s in isolation.

If anyone could indulge my curiosity, that would be greatly appreciated! Some things I looked into were asyncio, aiohttp, and aiomultiprocess, io.BytesIO etc. But I wasn't able to get them to work well with the tarfile library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation is likely **IO bound**. Compression is generally a slow task, especially the gzip algorithm (new algorithms can be much faster). From the provided information, the average reading speed is about 70 Mo/s. This means that the storage throughput is at least roughly 140 Mo/s. It looks like totally normal and expected. This is especially true if you use a HDD or a slow SSD.

Besides this, it seems you *iterate over the files twice* due to the selection of `members`. Keep in mind that tar gz files are a big block of files packed together and then compressed with gzip. To iterate over the filenames the tar file need to be already partially decompressed. This may not be a problem regarding the implementation of `tarfile` (possible caching). If the size of all the discarded files is small, it may be better to simply decompress the whole archive in a raw and then remove the files to discard. Moreover, if you have a lot a memory and the size of all discarded files is not small, you can decompress the files in an *in-memory virtual storage device* first in order to write the discarded files. This can be natively done on Linux systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. IJust checked the numbers (this is a network-attached hard disk drive in google cloud). The performance metrics are as follows:

Sustained random IOPS limit Read: 187.5
Sustained random IOPS limit Write: 375
Sustained throughput limit Read: 30 MB/s
Sustained throughput limit Write: 30 MB/s

How would I go about using an in-memory virtual storage device? Also, is 16GB of memory considered enough for this approach? 

(The size of the discarded files is relatively large, as they contribute to about 70% of the archive size)

Comment: On linux machines `/tmp` is sometimes mounted in memory and you need nothing special but extracting the files in `/tmp` (or any subdirectory). If this is not the case, then you can use `/dev/shm`. But be aware that the default memory space is limited and you probably need to resize it. For more information, see [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs).  https://unix.stackexchange.com may help you too ;) .